# Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.2) bower missing under dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-2017, bower, asp.net-core-2.0

So i just installed a clean version of Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017 Community.

Trying to create a brand new ASP.NET Core 2.0 project i saw that `Bower` is missing under the `Dependencies` node.

[image]

`Bootstrap` and `jquery` packages are already installed but i cannot manage them and cannot seem to find a configuration file either.

I searched the web for this problem but didn't found nothing useful.

Is there an issue with the VS 15.5.2 update? How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you seen Shawn's post? `ASP.NET Core 2.0 and the End of Bower`:
 https://wildermuth.com/2017/11/19/ASP-NET-Core-2-0-and-the-End-of-Bower
(I'm not sure this is an answer to you question)

Comment: You're right... This kinda explain something but not why i have packages installed and working and no config file, bower or any kind of file to manage them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is very annoying, but I guess the Manage Bower Packages context menu is now enabled only when you have the respective bower configuration file (bower.json) and right-clicking it.

Just create a new file *bower.json* and *.bowerrc* in the root directory project (nested solution) as respectively showed below:

```js
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

```js
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

A good hint to create any file is using *Mads Kristensen's* extension **[Add New File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.AddNewFile)** (SHIFT + F2) already embedded in **Web Essentials Extension (recommended)** also created by him.

So, right-click ***bower.json***.

[image]

[image]